# Migration to SQL Server 2014 Web Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am considering migrating one of our servers to SQL Server 2014 Web Edition to take advantage of SPLA licencing, however I am uncertain whether I can restore a backup to do the migration.

Can I restore a SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition backup file (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 X64 / Compatibility level 100) on SQL Server 2014 Web edition?

I have looked at the compatibility matrix on MSDN with regards to features and I'm happy with that - there's nothing unusual about the setup it just uses full text indexing which is supported in both versions and there is no backup encryption. I'm just concerned about the database rejecting the backup file....